# Interface with one method vs __invoke

Tags: php

Im reading about CQRS and I have just came across action handlers instead of good, old MVC controllers (so instead of AuthController with a bunch of actions/methods you transform each method into handler class).

What is new to me is a callabe class (the handler) with a single method `__invoke`. Until now I would create an interface with one method called handle and make my action handlers implement this interface. This is how I was taught.

On the other hand this invoke thing looks fancy. Generally I dont like using magic methods in PHP, mostly cause it’s magic, but this method is different. It makes perfect sense, cause my interface is imitating this behaviour. Afaik Java doesnt have such magic method so they have to implement Runnable (or something) but if we - as PHP developers - have it, why not to use it?

I dont want to fall inside this Enterprisy-Java-Developer trap and keep my interface for all cost if there is a „simpler” approach. Can you give some pros and cons of using both approaches?

Personally this magic method doesnt feel right to me, but I am biased and this is why I would like to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using the `__invoke`-magic method. Even the `callable` type hints work for this pattern.

```
class a {
    public function __invoke() {
        echo "OK!";
    }
}

function b(callable $x) {
    $x();
}

$a = new a();
$a();
b($a);
var_dump(is_callable($a));
```

The good thing about this is, it fits perfectly in the scheme and gives you the power to create methods which expect an callable type and even pass complex "lambdas" like whole classes instead of "simple" closures.

The only downside about this method - it complicates things for beginners, which don't know about them (like all other magic methods). And like all other magic methods, this has also some performance impacts. But in this case, the overhead is that small, that you shouldn't care about.